# How to invoke a call to a not overridden derived class function?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Base {
virtual void func1();
}

class Derived : Base {
void func1();
void func2();
}

vector<Base *> vec;
vec.push_back(new Base()), vec.push_back(new Derived());
```

What is the correct/clean way to call func2 **without** knowing which index corresponds to which class? Is there a convention to do such a thing? I also want to avoid using **typeid**.

Comment: You mentioned you don't know which index corresponds to which class, but still need to call `func2()`. Thus you cannot guarantee that `func2()` will be called for `Derived` objects. Which result do you expect from calling `func2()` for `Base` objects?

Comment: You might want to read about [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I'd like a way to know the class type maybe? I'm open to any other solutions :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry I know about object slicing....I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: What is the point of using a polymorphic vector when you want to use it in a non-polymorphic way? Cant you just use two vectors (one for `Base` objects and one for `Derived` obejcts) ?

Comment: @mkmostafa the whole point of accessing objects through a base class, is that you want to use the interface they are all guaranteed to have without having to know the specific details of the run-time types. So your question kinda subverts the whole principle of object-oriented programming (in particular, polymorphism). Now of course there are ways to find out the run-time type, but it would probably be better if you explained to us what `Base`, `Derived`, `func1` and `func2` _actually_ are in your code and we might be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: Can you edit `Base` and `Derived` in your example or may they be defined out of your reach (e.g. in a 3rd party library)?

Comment: @SimonKraemer yes I can!

Comment: if you can edit the classes it is trivial, just add a `func2(){}` to the base

Comment: @mkmostafa your original question used `vector<Base>`, not `vector<Base*>`. True, you changed it before any answer was posted, but people had already started writing them. Edits that invalidate answers aren't well accepted. That's why another user rolled your edit back. I think now all the answers are based on your updated code, so it can be fine; but in case it happens again, please do not make an edit that invalidates answers. Instead, ask a new question, maybe with a link to the original.

Comment: @FabioTurati Only two people posted answers based on the first revision and I replied to each one of them That I updated the question!...People started to answer based on the new updates and then someone rolls my question back?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will take one of said pointers and call func2 if possible, and simply return false otherwise

```
bool CallFunc2(Base* Bae){
  Derived* Der;
  if (Der = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(Bae))
    {Der->func2(); return true;}
  else
    return false;
}
```

This works on the principle that dynamic_cast returns a null pointer if the object being cast cannot be converted.

Comment: I'm using a vector of pointers! someone edited my question and changed it to just objects!!

Comment: @SimonKraemer No that someone was not me. The question had a problem I fixed it. Then someone rolls it back to the first revision.

Comment: @mkmostafa You're right. I misinterpreted the history as the initial version was folded...

Comment: @SimonKraemer no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case the objects are sliced, as mentioned in king_nak's answer, so there's no safe way to call `func2()`.
But you can store pointers to Base instead of Base objects - in this case you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
std::vector<Base*> vec;
vec.push_back(new Base());
vec.push_back(new Derived());

for (auto obj : vec)
{
    Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj);
    if (d)
    {
        d->func2();
    }
}
```

Some info on `dynamic_cast`: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

PS: Also, if you want to call function `func2()` on `Base` objects, I think it makes sense to add a stupid implementation to `Base` class and make the function `virtual`.

Comment: @mkmostafa anyway, you can use `dynamic_cast` to solve this problem. Also, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to solve original problem with object slicing, but it's highly unsafe

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Dynamic cast is the way to go. Everyone agreed on that ;).  I do not have a problem with object slicing, just someone edited my post and changed the pointers to objects :/ Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use RTTI at all (including `dynamic_cast`), you could simulate its behaviour like Qt does it with [`qgraphicsitem_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast)

Outline:

```
class Base {
public:
    enum { Type = 0 };
    virtual int type() { return Type; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    enum { Type = 1 };
    int type() { return Type; }
};

template<typename T>
inline T myobject_cast(Base *b) {
    if (b) {
       // Requires C++11
       if (int(std::remove_pointer<T>::type::Type) == b->type()) {
          return static_cast<T>(b);
       }
       /* Pre C++11 (might be UB, but works on many compilers, OpenSource and Commercial)
       if (int(static_cast<T>(0)->Type) == b->type()) {
          return static_cast<T>(b);
       }
       */
    }
    return NULL;
}

// use:
Base *b = new Base;
Base *d = new Derived;
Derived *o1 = myobject_cast<Derived*> (b); // NULL
Derived *o2 = myobject_cast<Derived*> (d); // d
```

Each class would require a unique `Type` member for this to work.

Be aware that this will not work with "intermediate" classes in the hierarchy. Only the actual, most derived type will can be cast to (e.g. a `DerivedDerived` cannot be cast to a `Derived`, or `Base` for that matter).

You might also find an overload for const handy:

```
template<typename T> inline T myobject_cast(const Base *b)
{ return (b && int(static_cast<T>(0)->Type) == b->type()) ? static_cast<T>(p) : 0; }

const Base *cb = new Derived;
const Derived *co = myobject_cast<const Derived *>(cb);
```

Comment: I had this idea to just add a function that gets the type in the super class an override it everywhere. But I wanted something simpler. I think the dynamic cast is the way to go ;).... Thanks :)

Comment: Use `T::Type` instead of `static_cast<T>(0)->Type` (I'm not sure if your version is UB or not).

Comment: That won't do, unfortunately. As `T` is `Derived*`, it would generate `Derived*::Type`, which is not correct. Regarding UB, I don't know for sure either. But Qt is used on quite a variety of platforms and supports many compilers, so it is quite safe to use. But alas, not 100% sure...

Comment: So `std::remove_pointer_t<T>::Type` to manage pointer correctly.